# How to search specific string form list in multithreaded environment.?

Tags: multithreading, java-8

Suppose i have a 4 List which contains String object.

Example:

```
List<String> str1;
List<String> str2;
List<String> str3;
List<String> str4;
```

Suppose below value are stored in List str1, str2, str3 and str4 respectively.

```
str1 = [i, need , help.]
str2 = [This , is , a , good , program.]
str3 = [i, need ,solution.]
str4 = [i, need , solution, using ,multi-thread,concept.]
```

Now i need to search a string "good" from the list using a multi-threaded concept.  Where for each list we will have an independent thread running in parallel and as soon as any thread finds the string name "good" all the other thread will get destroyed and on console we print the running Thread name and the List in which the String has been found.

I need a solution from someone since this is new to me and I have no idea how to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8 you could do it like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class MultithreadedSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> str1 = Arrays.asList("i ", "need ", "help.");
        List<String> str2 = Arrays.asList("This ", "is ", "a ", "good ", "program.");
        List<String> str3 = Arrays.asList("i", "need ", "solution.");
        List<String> str4 = Arrays.asList("i ", "need ", "solution ", "using ", "multi-thread ", "concept.");

        CompletableFuture<Void> cf1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(search(str1, "good"));
        CompletableFuture<Void> cf2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(search(str2, "good"));
        CompletableFuture<Void> cf3 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(search(str3, "good"));
        CompletableFuture<Void> cf4 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(search(str4, "good"));

        CompletableFuture.anyOf(cf1, cf2, cf3, cf4).join();
    }

    private static Runnable search(List<String> list, String searchString) {
        return () -> list.stream().filter(x -> x.trim().equals(searchString)).findFirst().ifPresent(x -> {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("List: " + list);
        });
    }

}
```

You have one CompletableFuture for each list of strings, executing a Runnable that performs the search, and with CompletableFuture.anyOf, the first CompletableFuture finding the search string wins.

**[EDIT: Java 7]**

As you asked, in Java 7 you could use a ForkJoinPool, but it is somewhat less elegant:

```
public class MultithreadedSearch2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        List<String> str1 = Arrays.asList("  ", "i ", "need ", "help.");
        List<String> str2 = Arrays.asList("This ", "is ", "a ", "  ", "program.");
        List<String> str3 = Arrays.asList("i", "need ", "solution.");
        List<String> str4 = Arrays.asList("i ", "need ", "solution ", "using ", "multi-thread ", "concept.", " ");

        Callable<Result> t1 = search(str1, "good");
        Callable<Result> t2 = search(str2, "good");
        Callable<Result> t3 = search(str3, "good");
        Callable<Result> t4 = search(str4, "good");

        ForkJoinPool executor = new ForkJoinPool();
        executor.invokeAny(Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3, t4)).output();
    }

    private static Callable<Result> search(final List<String> list, final String searchString) {
        return new Callable<Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result call() throws Exception {
                for (String s : list) {
                    if (s.trim().equals(searchString)) {
                        return new Result(Thread.currentThread(), list);
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception("nothing found");
            }

        };
    }

    private static class Result {
        private final Thread thread;
        private final List<String> list;

        public Result(Thread thread, List<String> list) {
            this.thread = thread;
            this.list = list;
        }

        public void output() {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + thread.getName());
            System.out.println("List: " + list);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Lars Gendner, Could you let me know how to do this in java 7.

Comment: Added a Java 7 example to my answer.